# gerrit 2.15 migration my changes links are broken

Tags: gerrit

I was trying to migrate from gerrit 2.14 to gerrit 2.15.
I ran the first step with no issues:
java -jar /var/gerrit/bin/gerrit.war init -d $GERRIT_HOME
But when I ran this it failed:
java -jar /var/gerrit/bin/gerrit.war reindex -d $GERRIT_HOME

The error message I see is:

```html
gerrit | [2018-12-03 18:09:33,831] [Index-Batch-1] ERROR com.google.gerrit.server.project.SubmitRuleEvaluator : Error looking up change 2
gerrit | com.google.gwtorm.server.OrmException: No patch set found
gerrit | at com.google.gerrit.server.project.SubmitRuleEvaluator.init(SubmitRuleEvaluator.java:665)
gerrit | at com.google.gerrit.server.project.SubmitRuleEvaluator.evaluate(SubmitRuleEvaluator.java:229)
gerrit | at com.google.gerrit.server.query.change.ChangeData.submitRecords(ChangeData.java:950)
gerrit | at com.google.gerrit.server.index.change.ChangeField.storedSubmitRecords(ChangeField.java:666)
```

I was looking at these instructions:
https://www.gerritcodereview.com/2.15.html

I know that in gerrit2.15 there is a change over to notedb. It appears from the documentation that I only need to run the init step. Regardless if I run the index I get an error when I click on any link from the gerrit's "my changes" page. I see this error:

```html
Cannot display change 2406 because it has no revisions.
```

Is there some more setup required for notedb? Or what am I missing?

Comment: Have you migrated to notedb (java -jar gerrit.war migrate-to-note-db -d $GERRIT_HOME)?

Answer (score 0):

It appears the problem went away when I removed the plugins.

This was the list of plugins I was using:

```html
download-commands
replication
importer
its-jira
commit-message-length-validator
deleteproject
reviewnotes
```

I will narrow it down to which one specifically was causing a problem.

Comment: Did you get a chance to identify which plugin was causing the reindex error?